# What is (are) the accidental cause(s) most feared by the flight crew?

Tags: accidents, accident-investigation, crew

As the question says, which is the accidental cause most feared (in general) by the flight crews and what's the reason of it?

Apart from hijacking, pilot incapacity or that kind of issues, I am referring to causes like aircraft systems failure, fire on cabin, etc.

**Observation:** I'm not asking this question to be an opinion question, since I want to know in general, what is this cause and reason(s) to be the most feared accidental cause.

Comment: I doubt that you can get an answer that does not involve some opinion since flight crew members vary widely as to what they fear, which of course is true of the general population. Also, answers would, in my opinion, also vary greatly depending on level of experience, type of equipment, where in the world you were operating, who or what you were carrying, etc. Just one example, when I was flying freight that was loaded in third world countries, my major concern was how badly underweighed it had been and how well it was secured. It will be interesting to see the answers you get.

Comment: Not being facetious, but the #1 most feared accident cause is crew error. I (as a crewchief) have muttered, and have heard my pilots say something to the effect of "Dear God, don't let me screw up."  Anecdotal, yes, but the question begs for anecdotal answers.

Comment: Are you including external causes, e.g. windshear at landing, or just looking for causes which origin is inside the aircraft, e.g. failures?

Comment: @mins I'm also including aerodynamic and meteo issues like those you've said.

Comment: I sincerely do not see how this can possibly be not opinion based, unless there has been a systematic poll among all crews (commercial, military, private) around the world.

Comment: Is it not possible to objectively discuss the opinions of a large troup of people? Individually, "I like Brand A" and "I like Brand B" are just opinions, but "Brand A has greater market share among this group for these reasons" becomes a more factual & objective discussion.  To the extent that this question is NOT a poll of what each individual is most concerned with, I would suggest it meets the intent of the rules & is a worthwhile topic. JMHO.

Comment: @RalphJ that's the point, how do you check the "market share" of the different fears? has someone ever polled worldwide flight crews about that? how often? was it an internet poll or a scientifically accurate one?

Comment: My data isn't quantitative, but is based on having worked with, trained with, and talked with hundreds of military and airline pilots over the course of a couple of decades.  Do I have a handle on what things concern pilots more than others? Even without *scientific* polling, I'd suggest that I do. I'll let the community here make the call.

Answer (score 6):

What crews *should* be most concerned with is indeed crew error.  In the 1930's and 1940's, more accidents were caused by mechanical failures -- things failed that made the airplane unrecoverable.  Several decades ago, crew errors became the larger source of accidents, where a flyable aircraft (albeit with perhaps some issue, but flyable nevertheless) crashed because the crew did something that made the situation worse.  The hardware these days is pretty darned reliable, and if "you" do what you're supposed to do, chances are really excellent that you can get it on the ground safely.

That said, pilot psychology plays a major role in answering the question, since pilots strongly prefer to be "in control."  Or, less formally, we all tend to be control freaks.  (Not *necessarily* in every area of our lives, but certainly in the cockpit, we tend to have "take charge" personalities.  If something isn't right, we want to make it right, and a *laissez faire* "eh, whatever" attitude doesn't tend to be found among pilots at work.)

So the things that most concern us at a more visceral level, I'll suggest, tend to be the things that we can NOT control.  If an engine catches fire, I'm confident I can put it out with the procedures and tools that I have, and I can get the aircraft back on the ground because I'm trained to do that even with one less engine than usual.  But if there is a raging fire someplace that I can't control (electrical wires -- [SwissAir Flight 111](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swissair_Flight_111) or cargo hold -- [ValueJet Flight 592](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ValuJet_Flight_592)), then that bothers me.  Similarly, Terry's scenario of cargo loading done wrong -- outside my control, and the pilots have to trust that somebody else did their job correctly.  And by the nature of that being entirely outside my control, that tends to be more of a troubling scenario than any of the typical list of things that I can control and have been trained for: engine fire, depressurization, electrical issues, etc.

Comment: I have also heard the uncontrollable fire as being what pilots fear the most a lot.  Especially in the middle of the Atlantic (or Pacific).  With lithium ion batteries, it could really happen at any point in the flight too.

Comment: This answer contains a lot of interesting points, but does not answer the question `which is the accidental cause most feared (in general) by the flight crews?` and rather `what **could be** the accidental cause most feared (in general) by the flight crews?` and hence is speculation.

Comment: @Federico Feel free to edit, if you want to make it more appropriate! Thank you.